# PixelGrabber значение пикселей

Tags: java, изображения, color

прога использует PixelGrabber для сканирования пикселей:

```
int pixels[]=new int[width*height];
PixelGrabber grabber= new PixelGrabber(pic,0,0,width,height,pixels,0,width);
try{
grabber.grabPixels();
}catch(InterruptedException e){}
```

если теперь вывести массив pixels, то получим:

для черного цвета: -16777216

для белого: -1

для зеленого: -16744704

Подскажите кто в курсе как образуются эти цифры , и почему они ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давай сразу преобразуем эти числа в шестнадцатиричные:

```
-16777216 = FF000000 (черный)
-1 = FFFFFFFF (белый)
-16744704 = FF007F00 (зеленй)
```

Будем смотреть на последние 6 штук 16-ричных символов

```
-16777216 = FF000000 ~ 000000 (черный)
-1 = FFFFFFFF ~ FFFFFF (белый)
-16744704 = FF007F00 ~ 007F00 (зеленй)
```

После этого становится очевидно, что меняются только они, а предыдущие 2 не меняются. Можно предположить, что это альфа канал. FF значит 255, следователно цвет не прозрачен. Вывод: это ARGB код, где первые 2 значения - это альфа, вторые 2 значения - это красный, третьи 2 значения - это зеленый, четвертые 2 значения - это синий.

А отрицательные они потому что данное число (двоичное число) представляется как знаковое, и если первый бит равен 1 - число отрицательное, если первый бит равен нулю - число положительное. Подробнее тут: [Вики, представление чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29)